# Define center of map in Mapbox

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I'm creating a viewer using Mapbox, the viewer will be full screen. However one half of the screen will be covered with a floating UI component. Therefor if the map zooms to a feature it should position the feature in the center of the other half of the screen. What would be a good way to approach this?

Currently when I zoom to a feature it will look like this, covered by the UI component:

[image: Currently when I zoom to a feature it will look like this, covered by the UI component:]

I want it to automatically center on one half of the viewer, like this:

[image: I want it to automatically center on one half of the viewer, like this:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`fitBounds` method](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#fitbounds) allows you to pass an option for [padding](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#paddingoptions), for example:

```
map.fitBounds([[min_lon, min_lat], [max_lon, max_lat]], {
    padding: {
        top: 5,
        bottom: 5,
        left: 5,
        right: document.getElementById('your_div').offsetWidth + 5
    },
    linear: true,
    duration: 0
});
```